# Repeat numerically increasing CSS classes with similarly named background image assets

Tags: css, emmet

Is it possible with [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) to shorthand this CSS? Each class corresponds to an image asset and they share an increasing number.

```
.penguin1 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_1.png'); }
.penguin2 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_2.png'); }
.penguin3 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_3.png'); }
.penguin4 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_4.png'); }
.penguin5 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_5.png'); }
.penguin6 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_6.png'); }
.penguin7 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_7.png'); }
.penguin8 { background-image:url('penguin_pngs/mound_8.png'); }
```

I am able to use CSS shorthand such as `bgi` which expands to `background-image: url();` but is it possible to repeat the classname and use a numbering operator such as Emmet's html `$` operator?

Comment: I'm not up on the latest emmet advances but I don't believe so. SASS/LESS certainly could though.